# PHP imagefilter function problem

Tags: php, gd, imagefilter

I have a problem with the imagefilter function I get the first example to work but not the second or third examples to work can some one help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Example 1 will work.

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng('dave.png');

if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE))
{
    echo 'Image converted to grayscale.';

    imagepng($im, 'dave.png');
}
else
{
    echo 'Conversion to grayscale failed.';
}

imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Example 2 wont work

```
<?php
if(!file_exists('dw-bw.png')) {
  $img = imagecreatefrompng('dw-manipulate-me.png');
  imagefilter($img,IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
  imagepng($img,'db-bw.png');
  imagedestroy($img);
}
?>
```

Example 3 wont work.

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng("space.png");
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, 50);
header("content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: I can get filter to apply to example 2 and 3

Comment: @gam what result do you get? What error messages? Please always describe exactly what happens. Do you get the unmodified image?

Comment: I get no messages and no modified images uni.

Comment: Do you get the unmodified image or no image at all?

Comment: the original image has no changes what so ever.

Comment: I've tested the code locally and it worked very well. Did you try example 2 and 3 with the image from example 1?

Answer (score 0):

> the original image has no changes what so ever
>   Because you write into a different file, dw-manipulate-me.png -> db-bw.png - and only if the db-bw.png file does not exist yet.